# Changing a variable value/re referencing it with SetIncrement

Tags: javascript, html

I have a timer I use to count how many masks are made in a production environment. I use a variable value that is user input when the page is started - it is called SAMS, basically how many masks 1 person can make in an hour would be what I would input depending on how many people I have working. IE. 2 people may be 18, 1 may be 9 etc. The problem I have with my current build is that I cannot change the SAMS value if I have someone leave for the day. So then what I use that value to calculate is off (I use it to show a GOAL value that increments based on the value).

Here is the relevant code for the processes I've described.

```
var SAMSINPUT = input;
console.log(SAMSINPUT);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = SAMSINPUT;
var goal = 0;
var output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
setInterval(function doIncrement() {
    if (clear == false) {
    goal += 1;
    output2.innerHTML = goal.toString();
    }
}, SAMSINPUT * 1000);
```

I also have START/STOP/RESET buttons on the page for the timer itself. I tried putting the SAMSINPUT input into the stop button, because if I could stop it, put in a new SAMSINPUT - and have the increment adjusted to the new value, that would solve this for me. However, that doesn't seem to change the actual value that SetInterval references, if I start with a 5, then change it to a 10 that way, it still increments at 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? Let me know if you have any problems/issues.

```js
var SAMSINPUT = 1;
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = SAMSINPUT;
var goal = 0;
var output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
function doIncrement() {
  goal += 1;
  output2.innerHTML = goal.toString();
}
var inter = setInterval(doIncrement, SAMSINPUT * 1000);

function changeAmount() {
  var newVal = document.getElementById('newval').value
  clearInterval(inter);
  var a = setInterval(doIncrement, newVal * 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>
</div>

<div id='output2'>
</div>
<input type="number" id="newval">
<button onclick='changeAmount()'>new SAMSINPUT</button>
```